# Timeout with CompletableFuture and CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

I want to wrap a `Runnable` in `CompletableFuture` to be computed asynchronously, but with control over when does the computation begin and end. I've created a `CompletableFuture` with `CountDownLatch` to block the processing, but the following snippet throws an error:

```
CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
CompletableFuture completableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        countDownLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Stop");
});
Thread.sleep(1000L);
System.out.println("Start");
completableFuture.get(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
countDownLatch.countDown();
```

> Start
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1771)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
>       at Sandbox.main(Sandbox.java:23)

When I call `get` without timeout on the other hand, it freezes (only `Start` is printed).

I expect the runnable in `CompletableFuture` to run when `countDownLatch.countDown();` is called.

Comment: `completableFuture.get(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` - you are blocking for 1000 ms and immediately after you will get that `TimeoutException`, no chance for main thread to reach `countDownLatch.countDown()`

Comment: @Eugene read on - without timeout `Stop` is never printed either

Comment: of course it's not - that code is not even reached. add two more `Syso` statements around `countDownLatch.await();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of `CompletableFuture#get` is a blocking call. So, `countDownLatch.countDown();`  will not execute till the time `CompletableFuture#get` get the result. `CompletableFuture` will not complete and return the result as it will wait to countDownLatch to count down. So, basically you have created a dependency between 2 thread such that one will wait for another and vice-versa.

Answer (score 5):

You are waiting till the timeout expires without allowing the thread to proceed. The `Future.get` is blocking and that will never allow you to `countDown` the `Latch` before the timeout expires ever, hence your thread never completes. What you have to do here is, first, let the thread proceed by calling the `countDown` on the `Latch` and then wait with a timeout in the get call. Just inverting the two lines would solve the issue. Here's how it looks.

```
countDownLatch.countDown();
completableFuture.get(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

In fact, if you remove the timeout from the get call (it blocks indefinitely), then this is a typical example of a Deadlock in a system. The worker thread waits until the main thread counts down the latch, while main thread waits for the worker thread to complete so that it can go ahead and countDown the latch. Fortunately, the time out passed to get enables Probabilistic deadlock avoidance. On the contrary, you can `cancel` the future at any time and avoid potential deadlocks as far as your tasks are responsive to the interruption.